# Is it possible to construct a graph backwards in TesorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering whether it is possible to construct this graph backwards, so instead of:

```
n1 = tf.add(2,3)
n2 = tf.add(2,n1)
n3 = tf.add(n1,n2)
```

this way:

```
n1 = None
n2 = None
n3 = tf.add(n1,n2)
n2 = tf.add(2,n1)
n1 = tf.add(2,3)
```

Ideally without any additional structure, and necessarily without loss of performance.

Comment: I don't know of an obvious way to do what you need, but maybe you can explain a bit more of the larger problem you're trying to solve? The Python bindings are a convenience, but you can always hand-construct NodeDefs to create graphs in any way you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the standard TensorFlow ops such as `tf.add()`, *all* inputs to the op must have been constructed before you construct the op. This is a deliberate design choice to make it harder to accidentally construct invalid graphs (e.g. with an ill-formed cycle).

However, as Pete notes in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879040/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-graph-backwards-in-tesorflow#comment63238964_37879040), the TensorFlow Python bindings are just wrappers around functions that create `NodeDef` protocol buffers. In principle, you could create your own wrapper that makes it possible to create graphs backwards. Without understanding the use case better, it is unlikely that we will support this in the standard library, however.